# Como mandar variáveis de um .PHP para outro .PHP

Tags: php, html5, postgresql

**Tela login.php**, essa é a tela principal onde o usuário loga com CNPJ e senha.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']) ) {
        include('login.php'); //code is given below (used for database connection)
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $ret= pg_query( $dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE cnpj = '$user' AND senha = md5('$pass')");
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret);
        if($row == 0 ) {
            session_start(); #tentativa de jogar o $user para o Dashboard.php
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user; #isso faz parte da tentativa
            header("Location: Tela Login.php");
        }
        else {
            header('location: Dashboard\Dashboard.php');
        }
}
?>
```

> Abaixo desse php ^  tem todo o Html do **Tela Login.php** que por acaso eu dê *include* nele em outro arquivo .php, o mesmo puxa todo o arquivo, tanto html quanto php. Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja ele fica com 2 páginas uma em cima da outra, pois o Dashboard é assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código do **login.php** que faz conexão com o banco e cria um array com os dados da tabela. Ela já funciona pois testei previamente na **Tela Login.php**

```
<?php 
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=NomeDoHost port=Porta dbname=NomeDoBanco user=usuario password=Senha");
$query = "SELECT cpfcnpj_formata(cnpj), nome FROM pessoa WHERE cnpj = ''";
$resultado = pg_query($dbconn,$query);
#While para tentar passar os dados pro Dashboard.php
while($linha = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) 
{
    echo "CNPJ: " .$linha['cnpj'] . "-";
    echo "Senha em md5: ".$linha['senha'] ."-194171-";
    echo md5('194171');
    $usuario = $linha['cnpj'];
    $senha = $linha['senha'];
}
pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```

Tentei também usar *$_SESSION* ou dar *include* na página **Tela Login.php**, porém ambos não funcionam da forma que eu quero.
No momento estou querendo puxar dados do banco para usa-los como informação na tela, por exemplo: Mostrar o CNPJ da empresa que o usuário está conectado.

Porém eu puxo as informações do banco com o login que for digitado em um textbox($user) na **Tela Login.php**

**Dashboard.php abaixo**

```
<?php
session_start();
    $cnpj = $_SESSION['user'];
    echo $cnpj;
?>
```

Caso exista outra maneira de fazer o que estou tentando, estou aberto a novas perspectivas.

Comment: O objetivo é criar uma forma de manter o usuário logado em seu sistema?

Comment: O objetivo é usar o login(cnpj) para buscar informações no banco.

Comment: Então, no momento do login, você pega as informações do banco e joga na sessão assim não será necessário pegar essas informações novamente, eu vou atualizar a resposta pra colocar esse exemplo.

Comment: Atualizei aqui, uma coisa que percebi que sua lógica estava errada, você estava colocando a session quando não existia usuário, por isso que não tava funcionando, tomei a liberdade de mudar alguma coisas, testa ai pra ver se funciona, e me da um retorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um mini Exemplo de como você pode usar a **[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)**, dividi em 3 partes, index, test, e destroy, aonde index ele vai definir as variaveis, test onde você irá visualizar o que foi gravado na $_SESSION e por fim destruir toda ela (um possível logoff)

**index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
$_SESSION['user_data']['cnpj']= '123.13.13.13.';
$_SESSION['user_data']['id']= 12;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a href="test.php">test</a> <br>
    <a href="destroy.php">destroy</a> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a href="destroy.php">destroy</a> <br>
    <a href="index.php">index</a> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

**destroy.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Inicia a sessão
session_destroy();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <a href="test.php">teste</a> <br>
    <a href="index.php">index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Você também pode usar o **[`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php);** especificando qual $_SESSION que excluir, no meu exemplo eu simplesmente definir sessão e abri em uma segunda pagina para que veja o funcionamento dela e a ultima pagina destruímos ela por completo.

Obs.: recomendo trabalhar com vetores fica mais fácil de se localizar o que você quer, por exemplo `$_SESSION['user_data']` aqui recebe um vetor com todos os dados do usuário que devem estar na sessão, dados que vão ser sempre carregados como nome, e etc, dados que devem a ser dinâmicos, como tabelas e forms esses sim devem vir diretamente do banco de dados.

**Adequando o form de login para seu problema.**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if( isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    include('login.php'); //code is given below (used for database connection)
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $ret= pg_query( $dbconn, "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE cnpj = '$user' AND senha = md5('$pass')");
    $count_row = pg_num_rows($ret);
    if($count_row == 0 ) { // se for igual 0 e porque não encontrou usuario
        header("Location: Tela Login.php");
    } 
    elseif($count_row > 1 ){
        // tem algo errado com seu banco só pode ter 1 usuario 
        header("Location: Tela Login.php"); // gambiarra pra evitar uma possivel falha de segurança. 
    }elseif ($count_row == -1) {
        //deu erro no sql
        var_dump($ret);
    }
    else {         
        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ret)){
            $_SESSION['user']['cnpj'] = $ret['cnpj'];
            $_SESSION['user']['outro campo que queria aqui'] = $ret['nome do outro cmapo'];

        }
        header('location: Dashboard\Dashboard.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Armazene essa variáveis em seção session() que elas estarão disponíveis nas demais páginas do seu sistema.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['test'] = 42;
        $test = 43;
        echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

Comment: Eu tentei com o **$_SESSION** por algum tempo e deu certo, depois do nada voltou a dar errado, parando pra pensar agora e testar seu código n faz sentido algum. Não  entendi o que quis mostrar com ele.